# How to fix: "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpResponse"

Tags: java, json, shopify, httpresponse, mashape

I'm trying to connect to our Shopify store to get JSON or String about our orders. I used generated code snippet from POSTMAN software for "Java Unirest":

```
    public void getNewShopifyOrders() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException, SQLException {
    try {
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) Unirest.get("https://nameStore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/orders.json")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic AuthenticationString")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .header("Postman-Token", "postmanToken")
                .asString();
        System.out.println(response);
        } catch (UnirestException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

}

I tried that generated code, and i needed to import

- Httpcomponents-client-4.5.8
- Httpcomponents-core-4.4.11
- unirest-java-1.4.9.jar
- Httppasyncclient-4.0-beta4.jar

But i'm still having issues, I needed to change code a bit because errors i've been getting are:

HttpResponse response = Unirest.get() - was having issue of "HttpResponse does not take Parameters" 
and after removing  it gives error:

```
     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpResponse
at quirkygiftliibrarydatabasemanager.Main_Window.getNewShopifyOrders(Main_Window.java:1816)
at quirkygiftliibrarydatabasemanager.Main_Window.jButton_RefreshShopifyOrdersActionPerformed(Main_Window.java:803)
at quirkygiftliibrarydatabasemanager.Main_Window.access$1200(Main_Window.java:44)
at quirkygiftliibrarydatabasemanager.Main_Window$14.actionPerformed(Main_Window.java:531)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: According to the _javadoc_ for static method `get()` of class `com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest`, the method returns an instance of `com.mashape.unirest.request.GetRequest` which is a subclass of `com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequest`. I don't think a `HttpRequest` is the same as a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a beginner in programming, could you provide me with piece of code i could try?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution to get JSON using Unires, here is the code to connect to Shopify shop to get order list:

```
     com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://shopName.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/orders.json").basicAuth("Api-Key", "Password").asJson();
   JSONObject myJSON = response.getBody().getObject();
```

I hope this will help other people as well :)